# how can I merge hdfs edit logs files?

Tags: hdfs

I have 20005 edit logs files in the NameNode which is a large number to me, is there a way I can merge them to fsimage ? I have restarted the NameNode, it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have HA enabled for NN, then you need to have a Secondary NameNode that does this.

If you have HA enabled, then your Standby NN does this.

If you have those, check for their logs and see what happens and why it fails. It is possible that you do not have enough RAM, and you need to increase the heap size of these roles, but that should be verified before with the logs.
If you do not have one of those beside the NN, then fix this and it will happen automatically, relevant configs that affect checkpoint timing:

```
dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period (default: 3600s)
dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns (default: 1 million txn)
```

You can run the following commands as well, but this is a temporary fix:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter
hdfs dfsadmin -rollEdits
hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Note: after entering safemode HDFS gets read only until you leave safemode.